# Merge PDF generated by MS Access 2016 with external PDF

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

Hei:
Im generating a Report on Print View and then saving it as a PDF on Access 2016.
The thing is I want to be able to attach, additionally, at the end of this report, an external technical sheet on pdf format.
What I have tried is to  make a Sub Report at the end of my main report, feeded by a table where I keep all the  technical sheets as OLE objects. In this sub report, i tried to display the ole object, with the he size of a whole page, but all I got was a little icon of the  pdf image displayed.
I also tried to attach it as an attachment, instead of OLE, but didnt worked.
Is there a way to be able to merge external pdfs with the pdf that generates Access?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your technical sheets are in the PDF format, you could simply output your access report as pdf and then combine that report with your technical sheets within your pdf reader.

If you have Adobe Acrobat reader:

File > Create > Combine Files Into a Single PDF

After you make this selection, you can rearrange your files in the order you would like.

Comment: Hei, I understand your suggestion, but do you think there is a way make that same step that you do with Acrobat Reader (Combine Files Into a Single PDF), but with the  Access itself?

Comment: Google around for your answer there. This looks like a promising page: [Merge PDFs in a folder](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47310-Need-code-to-merge-PDF-files-in-a-folder-using-adobe-acrobat-X)